# Google Analytics still recording stats even though site has been removed

Tags: seo, google-analytics

I've recently built a new site for a recruitment company, totally removed the old site, and added new analytics code, but it still seems to be tracking about 60 visits a day from the old site, which doesn't exist.

I've set up redirects - but I'm just wondering if anyone would have any idea why the old tracking code is still picking up visits?

Answer (score 1):

it's possible the tracker is on another site or cached somewhere else. In that case the javascript would still execute and send hits to Google Analytics.

Try the [Query Explorer](http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/), or create a custom report and include the hostname dimension to see what hostname the hits are associated with.